# How to play mp3 file in loop in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

I'm implementing a game for WP7, and I need that a mp3 file plays in background, while I navigate through some screens. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [background Audio agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for this purpose to play , even when user navigate between pages.

Also you can achieve the continuous playback by 2 ways
 1. set the repeat option to play continuously 
or 
2. start play back again upon receiving the stop message, this can be achieved by putting code for **starting playback again in Application Background player state handler upon receiving  "PlayState.Stopped" message**.

Please refer this link ["How to: Play Background Audio for Windows Phone"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: But remember, Background audio agent works for Wp7.1 applications only. No support in Wp7.0.

Answer (score 1):

Hm.. what about global MediaPLayer instance? 
See [this link](http://soonstudios.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/how-to-play-music-across-pages/)