# Play loop of sound in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio

i need to play a sound on the touch of screen, and it should remain in play state until user   get his hands off from the screen. here is the code of mine,

```
private void OnMouseDown(object sender, Moenter code hereuseButtonEventArgs e)
{
clicked = true;
ColoringSound.Source = new Uri("Sounds/drawing.mp3", UriKind.Relative);
ColoringSound.Play();
}
private void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
clicked = false;
}
```

Comment: Hope My answer , [in this post may help you.][1] Please check the same.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676183/how-to-play-mp3-file-in-loop-in-wp7

Comment: Thanks Santhu But my app is not not adding file like that. is this problem of version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an MSDN article that [describes how to loop MediaElements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741866.aspx), all you have to do to stop a looped sound is invoke the [Stop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.stop%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.